# Why do CORBA interfaces have a return type and an out keyword?

Tags: rpc, corba, idl

[I was reading about CORBA](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/idl/jidlExample.html) and I noticed something funny. CORBA interface methods are defined with a return type, for example `string` in

```
module HelloApp
{
  interface Hello
  {
  string sayHello();
  oneway void shutdown();
  };
};
```

and also has a keyword `out` which when passed as a parameter, means that value is returned. [For example here](http://www.ciaranmchale.com/corba-explained-simply/core-concepts-and-terminology.html#toc13)

```
struct Data { ... };
typedef sequence<Data> DataSeq;
interface DataIterator {
  DataSeq next_n_items(in unsigned long how_many);
  void    destroy();
};
interface SearchEngine {
  DataSeq query(
             in  string         search_condition,
             in  unsigned long  how_many,
             out DataSeq        results,
             out DataIterator   iter);
};
```

Seems redundant. **Why do you need both?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An operation can only have *one* return value, but can have a *multiple* out arguments. It is a user decision what to use, but in a lot of cases an operation returns one value and then it is easier for the user to have a return value so that he can write for example (using IDL to C++11):

```
int32_t my_result = foo->my_operation ();
```

Where with an out argument he has to write

```
int32_t my_result {};
foo->my_operation (my_result);
```

The first example is easier and also safer, no need to explicitly initialize my_result to its default value.